# VSCode Python debugging with context manager

Tags: python, vscode-debugger, with-statement, contextmanager

I have a code block such as the following:

```py
with Validator.start_server():
   return manager(foo=bar)
```

Where `Validator.start_server()` is set up as follows:

```py
class Validator:

   @staticmethod
   def start_server():
      
       @contextmanager
       def empty(bool):
          yield bool

       return empty(True)
```

I am trying to set a breakpoint on the `return manager(foo=bar)` line and stepping into the `manager` function. However, VSCode completely ignores that breakpoint and continues running. During the program execution, I can see in the debugger that there are threads/subprocesses running which I'm assuming are related to the context manager.

This is how my `launch.json` looks like:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "context-manager-debug",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/path/to/__main__.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "subProcess": true,
        },
}
```

Comment: can you add a complete example? I just tested it and it works

Comment: @fehrlich - sure, have a look at https://github.com/demisto/demisto-sdk/blob/master/demisto_sdk/__main__.py#L1330.

Answer (score 0):

Some workaround to unblock You despite whatever issues with VSC debugger usage You might have:

- using python built-in **pdb debugger** - just modify Your code to:

  - Python 3.7+:

  ```
   with Validator.start_server():
       breakpoint()
       return manager(foo=bar)
  ```

  - Pyhon <=3.6:

  ```
   with Validator.start_server():
       import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
       return manager(foo=bar)
  ```

It will let You step throughout the code within a commandline.

Enter "help" or eventually "help <cmd>" after the commandline shows up in Your terminal for more guidance on how to use it.

More details on the usage can be found in [pdb doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).